# Why would include(locate_template) work but not get_template_part()?

Tags: get-template-part

The parent theme uses this construct to include the navbar:

`include(locate_template( "components/navigation.php" ));`

I would prefer to use the Wordpress convention:

`get_template_part( "components/navigation" );`

in my child theme, to call the file from the parent theme, but his code works and mine doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

The surrounding code looks like this:

```
if ( $navigation_type != '' ) {
  include(locate_template( "components/navigation.php" ));
}
```

This code loads fine, the debug log is empty. If I switch that code to

```
if ( $navigation_type != '' ) {
  get_template_part( 'components/navigation' );
}
```

then The debug log fills with 
`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: navigation_type in /path/to/components/navigation.php on line 31`

Comment: `get_template_part` should work the way you use it. activate the debug mode to see if there is an error https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Debug Queries shows it is being correctly called, but there is no output. Strange, the debug log shows the encapsulating conditional var as undefined if I switch to get_template_part.

Comment: `$navigation_type` will be undefined in `/path/to/components/navigation.php` when using `get_template_part()` because the file is included in the `load_template()` scope and not the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

when you use get_template_part, your file navigation.php cannot access variable $navigation_type. but when you do include and locate_template it is simply like including a php file so it can access that variable. 
It is due to scope of variable in your context.

Comment: I'd just add that this would probably indicate that the original parent theme isn't so well written.

Comment: https://mekshq.com/passing-variables-via-get_template_part-wordpress/